# PHP force download of remote file without reading into memory

Tags: php, http-headers, buffer, remote-access, readfile

Is it possible to force a download of remote file in PHP without reading it into memory?  I know fpassthru(), readfile(), file_get_contents() all reads the files into memory before outputting it into the browser.

Here's my code:

```
if($url = getRemoteFileURL($file_id))
{
  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="abc.zip"');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Expires: 0');
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
  header('Pragma: public');
  header('Pragma: no-cache');

  readfile($url);  // is there a better function ?
}
```

I don't want to do header("Location: ") because that would reveal the URL

Comment: You could used a chunked fetch of the remote file, and dole out the pieces. But that'd require multiple http requests from your script and be quite inefficient.

Answer (score 3):

If you do a `header("Location: ...");` to a downloaded file, the URL isn't actually revealed much, if at all.

Anyway, `readfile` is probably your best option. I would assume, given that it writes straight to the output, that PHP proceeds by reading in a part of the file, then outputting it, then reading the next part, etc., overall using very little memory.

Comment: The URL is revealed to anyone savvy enough to have Inspector open and sometimes that is unacceptable. Also, you can't control the filename if you do that.

Comment: Yes Alec is right.  In Chrome, all you have to do is just go to your current downloads page and you can see the URL.  Also, readfile causes the script to run for as long as the file is being downloaded.  Not very efficient IMO.  For example, if I were downloading a 1GB file for 30 minutes, the script will be running for 30 minutes ( dont know if some servers will timeout for a script running that long)

Comment: Default max PHP script execution time is 30 seconds... so yes that won't work with the default value.

Comment: I'm on same boat i found this, i think it's a solution https://kovyrin.net/2010/07/24/nginx-fu-x-accel-redirect-remote/